# prove that this expression equals the area of a specific triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Prove that the area of a triangle with one of its angles $\frac{\pi}4$ rad, and the side opposite to this angle is $2$cm equals $\sin(2\theta)-\cos(2\theta)+1$, where $\theta$ is the angle adjacent to the $2$cm side.

and here is a picture to make things cleaner:
[image]

Comment: Use the sine rule to find another side.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = 2, A = \frac {\pi} 4, B = \theta$

Then,

$$
\frac{b}{\sin \theta} = \frac{2}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}2}
\implies b = 2\sqrt 2 \sin \theta
$$

Then,

$$
\sin C = \sin(A+B) = \frac {\sqrt{2}}2 (\sin \theta + \cos \theta)
$$

Then,

$$
S = \frac 12 ab\sin C =\frac 12 \times 2\times 2\sqrt 2\sin \theta\times \frac {\sqrt{2}}2 (\sin \theta + \cos \theta)\\
= 2\sin \theta (\sin \theta + \cos \theta)=2\sin^2\theta+2\sin \theta \cos \theta = 1-\cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta
$$

Comment: I really appreciate for your answer!

Comment: @AmrWaleed You didn't mark the points with letters so I marked them. A is the known angle, a is the known side and B is $\theta$, mark these on the picture you provided and  you are set.

Comment: I asked about the step of law of sines, but i just recognized what you did there, thanks anyway